# Parametrization of vector field with an unknown vector potential

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$F$ is a vector field with unknown potential $A$ and there's a surface with the boundary of a unit circle at the origin. Also, the circulation $A$ around the unit circle oriented clockwise is a positive constant. Given this information, I know that the flux through the unit circle will give me the flux through the surface, or any surface.

How do I find $F$ given this information?
I've parametrized $F$ with $F(rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta),0)$ but I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: You do not find $F$ given this information. All you’ve done is state consequences of Stokes’s Theorem. By the way, $A$ is called the vector potential.

Comment: Then is it not possible to find the flux of F through this surface? Or can that be done indirectly somehow?

Comment: The *flux* of $F$ is the given circulation of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to find the vector field $F$ that
satisfies
$$
F=\nabla\times A\,,\quad\oint_{S^1}A\cdot ds=c
$$
for some constant $c>0\,.$

- This problem does not have a unique solution.

By Stokes,
$$
\int_{B_1(0)}F\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,dS=\int_{B_1(0)}(\nabla\times A)\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,dS=c\,.
$$
When $c=2\pi$ one solution is
$$
F=\nabla\times A=\nabla\times\pmatrix{-y\\x\\0}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\2}
$$
which has
$$
\oint_{S^1}A\cdot ds=2\pi= \int_{x^2+y^2\le 1}F\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,dS\,.
$$
When we add to this $F$ the vector field
$$
F'=\nabla\times A'=\nabla\times\pmatrix{-y^2\\x^2\\0}=2\pmatrix{0\\0\\x+y}
$$
which has
$$
\oint_{S^1}A'\cdot ds=0= \int_{x^2+y^2\le 1}F'\cdot\boldsymbol{n}\,dS
$$
we get another solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Can you explain how you got A to be <-y,x,0> and the curl to be <0,0,2>?

Comment: That $A$ is tangent to the unit circle. Draw a picture to see that, or take the dot product with the normal to the unit circle which is $(x,y,z)\,.$ I hope you know to calculate its curl to be $(0,0,2)\,.$ Similarly for $A'\,.$

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Just to be sure, we're breaking down the circulation of A and realizing we're looking at the component of A along the tangent of the unit circle. And then that would make A some <-y,x,0>.  Does that sound about right? And one last thing, what sort of generalization would I be making if I used the unit vector of F, <0,0,1>? Would I no longer be talking about a unit circle?

Comment: Honestly, these questions do not sound like you understand. You should just actively practice a bunch of line and surface integrals. When you search "verify" "Stokes" you should find plenty of them in MSE.